# Sorting Android Songs

Tags: android

New Android developer here; well versed in Java.
I'm looking to create a playlist maker and am having trouble sorting my media. I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i) but it does not cover how to sort the media by artist. I'd like to have a ListView of the artists and if you click an artist it expands down to show the albums by that artist, and then if you click an album it expands down to show the songs in that album. Keeping future capabilities in mind, I'd like to be able to drag and drop albums/songs.

I appreciate any help you have to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to look into is the Android Media Store.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Using the managedQuery function in an activity you can get a cursor to the MediaStore database. There are levels of URI in mediastore Artist, Album, or songs. You can sort out the information you want using that library.